# How to query data from many tables using UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union

I have 3 tables and would like to select data from `table1&table2`, then from `table3&table2`, and finally, concatenate both queries and get the last 10 elements of the result.
Each of these queries works fine. The problem occurs when I use `UNION`

```
SELECT t1.postID, 
       t1.status,
       t1.`number`, 
       t2.reference, 
       t2.joint_date
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.postID=t2.postID
WHERE t1.active=1 
AND t1.userID=3
ORDER BY t1.postID ASC
UNION
SELECT t3.postID, 
       t3.status,
       t3.`number`, 
       t4.reference, 
       t4.joint_date
FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table2 t4 ON t3.postID=t4.postID
WHERE t3.active=1 
AND t3.userID=3
ORDER BY t3.postID ASC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I am just getting an error.
How could I achieve this with one query ?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Those of use who know SQL know the error but it is important to include it in your post. That is what you and other devs will search on to find answers in the future. Please edit your post to include the actual error, we are expecting _"Unknown column 't3.postID' in 'order clause'"_

Comment: ORDER BY without TOP/LIMIT does nothing unless it is on the outside of a query; tables have no row order, result sets have row order. ORDER BY after a UNION of SELECTS orders the UNION, not the last SELECT. These are faqs. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining `UNION` and `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in a single query, it is important to recognise that `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will apply to the entire `UNIONED` result set. For this reason we can only specify `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` *after* the final query.

> The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in a query that has been concatenated with a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` are not actually part of the last expression, they are actually after it. For this reason you cannot use table aliases in the `ORDER BY`, instead you can only use the column alias that is defined in the first expression, before the first `UNION`.

If you want to get the *LAST* 10 records from your query then we can simply reverse the order of the `postID`:

```
SELECT t1.postID, 
       t1.status,
       t1.`number`, 
       t2.reference, 
       t2.joint_date
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.postID=t2.postID
WHERE t1.active=1 
AND t1.userID=3
   
UNION

SELECT t3.postID, 
       t3.status,
       t3.`number`, 
       t4.reference, 
       t4.joint_date
FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table2 t4 ON t3.postID=t4.postID
WHERE t3.active=1 
AND t3.userID=3

ORDER BY postID DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Notice that I have deliberately injected a space between the last expression and the `ORDER BY`, this is to highlight visually that the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in this query are part of the `UNION` and *not* part of the second query, the `ORDER BY` has also been removed from the first query as the overall result set will be re-ordered anyway.

Also note that we *do not need* (and cannot use) a table alias to reference the `postID` column.

Comment: Thanks @philipxy I realize that this is a basic issue of understanding of how `UNION` is executed. Unfortunately for most users who post, they are not likely to find or understand the dups if they are using the wrong terminology or assumptions from the outset. By answering we can provide a very context specific response that will help them in their journey.  As long as the message is correct I'm only wasting my time and hopefully not yours. What these users really need is access to a code mentor...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What the site needs is quality questions easily found. I'm not going to say more because mods punish for that.

Answer (score 0):

Place both halves of the union into separate tuples:

```sql
(SELECT t1.postID, t1.status, t1.`number`, t2.reference, t2.joint_date
 FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.postID = t2.postID
 WHERE t1.active = 1 AND t1.userID = 3)
UNION
(SELECT t3.postID, t3.status, t3.`number`, t4.reference, t4.joint_date
 FROM table3 t3
 INNER JOIN table2 t4 ON t3.postID = t4.postID
 WHERE t3.active = 1 AND t3.userID = 3
 ORDER BY t3.postID
 LIMIT 0, 5)
ORDER BY postID;
```

Note that the final `ORDER BY` clause applies to the entire result set after the union has finished.